# Ignored CSS styling for specific pages

Tags: css

As an example, i have 3 html which is **login.html**, **home.html**, and **contact.html**. all 3 of them have banner coded like so:

```
.
.
<div id="banner" class="banner" >
      ....
    </div>
.
.
```

and they also called a css file which contains the following

```
.
.
.    
.banner {
    background: url("images/image1.jpg");
}
.
.
```

i want to set image1.jpg background only for home.html and contact.html. ignore the css if the page is login.html . Is it possible **by only adjusting the css** file?

to make it clear, i want to do something like this:

```
.banner{
    if(page != login.html)
          background: url("images/image1.jpg");
    else
          ignore;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have **two** options:

1. Add a class to the `<body>` tag or the particular element.
2. Add an additional style sheet to overwrite the default styles.

If you can give the `body` a class `login` for the `login.html`:

```
<body class="login">

    <div id="banner" class="banner">
      ....
    </div>

</body>
```

You can overwrite the styles by adding like:

```css
.login .banner {background: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the HTML, you could also add a another class to your banner and reference it by `id` in your CSS.  Something like:

**HTML**

```
<div id="banner" class="banner home" >
      ....
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#banner.home {
    background: url("images/image1.jpg");
}

#banner.login {
    background: url("images/image2.jpg");
}
```